# Laravel LiveWire 2 : Do we have to make a new class or we can do like traditional Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, components, laravel-livewire

So, it's my first `LiveWire` learning Project.

Just to the point, I'm making a **Livewire Component** called **User** using `php artisan make:livewire user`

and then this is what I got

***First User.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class User extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.index'); //i've updated this
    }
}
```

And so, **I want to make a create user at different pages**. *NOTES: Ive already use turbolinks for the SPA*, and when I create like the traditional Laravel Controller like

***Web.php***

```
Route::get('/user', User::class)->name('user.index');
Route::get('/user/create',[User::class, 'create'])->name('user.create');
```

***User.php (livewire component)***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class User extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.index');
    }

    // This is what i create
    public function create()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.create')
        ->extends('layouts.app')
        ->section('contents');
    }
}
```

It **doesn't give me the parent templates** (It doesn't run into layouts.app and go to contents, it just show blank pages), I've tried to extends it with layouts.app and the section

***layouts/app.blade.php***

```
    <div class="flex h-screen bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900" :class="{ 'overflow-hidden': isSideMenuOpen }">
        @include('layouts.include._sidebar')
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 w-full">
            @include('layouts.include._navbar')
            <main class="h-full overflow-y-auto">
                <div class="container px-6 mx-auto grid">
                    {{-- {{ $slot }} --}}
                    @yield('contents')
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question:

can we do like standart laravel controller with **public function create inside user component** OR we have to **make a new component called UserCreate**? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by different ways, depend of you.
One can be have an UserForm component to handle the create/edit forms, and in User's create component call to render the UserForm component to create new one.

```
public function create()
{
   return redirect()->route('user.create');
}
```

in web.php

```
Route::get('/user/create', [UserForm::class])->name('user.create');
Route::get('/user/edit/{user?}', [UserForm::class])->name('user.edit');
```

and UserForm component

```
public $email, $name;
public $user;

public $option = '';
public function mount($user = null)
{
  if(is_null($user)) {
    // some initialization
    $this->option = 'create';
  }
  else {
    $this->user = User::find($user);
    $this->option = 'edit';
  }  
}

public function render()
{
   return view('user-form');
}

public funcion store()
{
   if($this->option == 'create') {
       //create handler
   }
   else {
       //edit handler
   } 
}
```

instead use redirect you can use modals and render UserForm inside a modal you have in User component. As I told you, this can be do it by different ways

Comment: the problem is, im not a fan of using modal. i want to go to different page, so if its different page, we have to make new component? like you said i have to make userform component for create/edit like you said

Comment: Ok, like I told you, that depend of you. In this case you render the create/edit component as Full Page Component. Another is by nested component (modals, dropdown toggles, etc). But yes, in my example you need a different component...this allow you reuse component and other handles

Comment: after doing research at livewire, i think modal is a thing in this and has big part for reuse component like u said, so i think this is the answer i looking for. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use livewire as full page components or components loaded in your view with `<livewire:component-name />`

You can only have the Livewire generated "controller" `User.php` or you can have a classic Laravel controller from where you return a blade view and in your blade view you can load the livewire component using `<livewire:component-name />`.

In your case, I think that in the render method you have to return `livewire.user` and in your blade view load it as mentioned above.

Comment: in this case, i want to make Single Page Application, so yeah i choose livewire generated component / controller. so i have static navbar, sidebar and a dynamicaly content than can change (we can choose user management / item management / something else for the content). do you think for this case its user, i want to make a create page, should i make new component like UserCreate.php or i can make it like classic laravel controller by making public function create inside userp.php and call the view?

Comment: "Like classic laravel controller". You define the methods in your Livewire controller and you bind them with `wire:click` in your view.

Comment: oh okay, so i make the public function create with return the create user view, and on the view (User view) i bind a button with wire:click (is this <a href> like classic link to other page or different approach?

Comment: Here's an example of Data Binding in Livewire: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding

Comment: Thanks for the example and effort to answer my question. i think i got my answer, ill mark you up for the effort you give :)